# How many vertices can you visit in a given distance in a closed walk

Tags: graph-theory, computational-mathematics

As the title says. Given a distance and a starting vertex, how many vertices can you visit in a closed walk. This is for work and right now the only solution I have is brute force calculating all closed walks less than or equal to the distance, so any ideas are more than welcome. Finite graph, weighted edges.

Comment: What do you mean by *distance*? Sum of weights along a path? Count of edges along a path (special case of the former where each edge has weight $1$)?

Comment: Do you have a particular graph in mind, or a general one?

Comment: I mean sum of weights. The graph is a physical 2D map where vertices are points of interest and edges are the geodesic between two points.